# Store filtering for combobox and bindStore

Tags: javascript, extjs, ext3

The store is bonded to the combobox with bindStore in a separate function.

It all works fine - except that i need to filter the data in that function based on the given parameters.

```
  loadMarkers: function(store, value){

    store.filter('markerid',17);

    this.fields.marker.bindStore(store);
    this.fields.marker.setValue(value);
  }
```

This specific example has  two diff ways iv tried it - before binding and after. Console.log at the end shows filtered store for both 'store' and even the combobox. But the combobox itself still shows everything.

combobox config:

```
  marker: new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    fieldLabel: _('Marker'),
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    mode:'local',
    lastQuery: '',
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
      fields: ['name', 'id', 'markerid'],
      data: [
        {name:_('Default'), id: 0, markerid: 0}
      ]
    })
   })

this.markerStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
  autoLoad: true,
  url: 'Api/getMarkers',
  root: 'response',
  sortInfo: {field: 'name', direction: 'ASC'},
  fields: Ext.data.Record.create([
    {name: 'id', type: 'integer'},
    {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'markerid', type: 'integer'}
  ])
});
```

Comment: Could you show your store config too

Comment: updated with store config

Comment: what version of Ext are you using mate? I'll post some code in a min

Comment: ext 3.4 (ext3 in the tags)

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming that you are using ExtJs 3.4 for this answer due to the format of the code above.

I tried to run your code directly and got a number of errors. Such as `_('Default') _() is undefined` and from what I can see in the documentation a ComboBox doesn't have a function called bindStore [ComboBox Documation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox).

I have rewritten the code into the below code and it works fine for me. You need to make sure that you are applying the filter AFTER the store has loaded the data, in my example I wait for the load event to be fired.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = '/js/ext-3.4.0/resources/images/default/s.gif';

    var markerStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        autoLoad: true,
        url: 'data/data1.json',
        root: 'rows',
        sortInfo: {field: 'name', direction: 'ASC'},
        fields: [
            {name: 'id', type: 'integer'},
            {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'markerid', type: 'integer'}
        ],
        listeners: {
            'load': function() {
                Ext.getCmp('createformTypeCombo').getStore().filter('markerid', 17);
            }
        }
    });


    var form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [
            new Ext.form.Label({
                text: "form",
                margin: "25 10 25 5"
            }),
            new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                fieldLabel: 'Marker',
                id: 'createformTypeCombo',
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'id',
                mode:'local',
                lastQuery: '',
                store: markerStore
            })
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: as for the _('Default') - can ignore that, remove the _() - those are special tags for  translation scripts.

Also bindStore is a private (docs don't show it by default).
I cant add the filter to the load event since the final filter value is dynamic and comes as a parameter for the function.

The store is loaded once and then needed results are filtered out later - to avoid excess queries to the server and db.

Comment: ok, If you try to add your filters on the load event this should resolve your issue, hopefully.